# Modify Virtual disk size using VI Java API

Tags: api, virtual-machine, vmware, vsphere

I'm trying to clone VM, and I want to change the disk capacity.

```
    int virtualDisksCount = 0;
    VirtualDisk virtualDisk = null;
    for (VirtualDevice virtualDevice : virtualHardware.getDevice()) {
        if (virtualDevice instanceof VirtualDisk) {
            virtualDisksCount++;
            virtualDisk = (VirtualDisk) virtualDevice;
        }
    }
    if (virtualDisksCount == 1) {
        VirtualDeviceConfigSpec discSpec = new VirtualDeviceConfigSpec();
        discSpec.setOperation(VirtualDeviceConfigSpecOperation.EDIT);

        virtualDisk.setCapacityInBytes(155500000000l);
        virtualDisk.setCapacityInKB(155500000000000000l);


        discSpec.setDevice(virtualDisk);

       return discSpec;
    }
```

The code throws exception : Invalid operation for device '0'.
I passed these parameters in CloneVm_Task and in ReconfigureVM_Task, the same errors happens

How can I change the virtual disk capacity? Using Vsphere 5.5

Comment: Encountered similar issue

Comment: I've found a fix. You can create a image with minimum needed HDD, say 10 GB then you should use DiskManager to extend the size. So we do only extending HDD no shrink

Comment: Are you referring to use virtualDiskManager data object? Can you help elaborate how to do this, we didn't even capture the DiskObjectId from VirtualDevice   - it returned NULL

Answer (score 1):

I don't code in Java, but it's close enough to C# for me to help.  First off to do this you need to get your disk info and then pull out the virtualdeviceconfigspec, change it, then add attach it back to the disk.  You are creating a new spec then setting the properties.  Also, why are you setting the size in bytes then kb???

Here is all the Java I could muster...

```
myDisk.setCapacityInKB(Long.parseLong(50)*1024*1024);
VirtualDeviceConfigSpec vdConfigSpec = new VirtualDeviceConfigSpec();
vdConfigSpec.setDevice(myDisk);
vdConfigSpec.setOperation(VirtualDeviceConfigSpecOperation.edit);
VirtualMachineConfigSpec vmConfigSpec = new VirtualMachineConfigSpec();
vmConfigSpec.setDeviceChange(new VirtualDeviceConfigSpec[]{vdConfigSpec});
Task task = vm.reconfigVM_Task(vmConfigSpec);
```

Comment: I won't post my code because it's too long and is C#.  This is the best code I could muster in Java (it's been years since I've used Java).  After you get the disk you want to change, this is the code you need.  I labeled the disk "myDisk".  I added the code to my answer above.  I hope it helps.  Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I tried the same, but says the operation edit is not allowed. I tried to use DiskManager API and it works. What version of vsphere do you use?

Comment: That's strange, it works when I do it.   I'm using vSphere 5.5.